# Xcode fails to build flutter code for ios 13.3.1 device but runs code on 13.3 ios simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, compiler-errors, xcode11.3

below is what I am getting on Xcode 11.3.1 and ios 13.3.1. what shall I do?
the code works on the ios simulator and builds for it is always successful. so where is the issue? what's wrong here, or am I missing some thing here?
I did try the clear / install pods method but nothing has been working for me.

```
iMac:x me$ flutter build  ios
The plugin `device_id` is built using an older version of the Android plugin API which assumes that it's running in a full-Flutter environment. It may have undefined
behaviors when Flutter is integrated into an existing app as a module.
The plugin can be updated to the v2 Android Plugin APIs by following https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Building com.x.demo for device (ios-release)...

Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: MHUCCU5SX2

Running pod install...                                              5.9s
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 ├─Building Dart code...                                    61.5s
 ├─Generating dSYM file...                                   1.0s
 ├─Stripping debug symbols...                                0.9s
 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           1.9s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        20.5s
Xcode build done.                                           239.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    The plugin `device_id` is built using an older version of the Android plugin API which assumes that it's running in a full-Flutter environment. It may have
    undefined behaviors when Flutter is integrated into an existing app as a module.
    The plugin can be updated to the v2 Android Plugin APIs by following https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
    Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...          
    Building App.framework for arm64...

    Building App.framework for armv7...
    Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...             60.1s
    Built to build/aot/.
    warning: parsing line table prologue at offset 0x6f697463 found unsupported version 0x00
    warning: line table parameters mismatch. Cannot emit.
    note: while processing /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/aot/armv7/snapshot_assembly.o
    The plugin `device_id` is built using an older version of the Android plugin API which assumes that it's running in a full-Flutter environment. It may have
    undefined behaviors when Flutter is integrated into an existing app as a module.
    The plugin can be updated to the v2 Android Plugin APIs by following https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
    Project /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x built and packaged successfully.
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/ios/Flutter/App.framework/App, building for iOS-armv7 but
    attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/ios/Flutter/App.framework/App, building for iOS-arm64 but
    attempting to link with file built for iOS Simulator-x86_64
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    Ld
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axlithrrzxajtgfxqkefalkhujgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objec
    ts-normal/arm64/Binary/Runner normal arm64
    /* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning:
    The app icon set "AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning:
    The app icon set "AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
    /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@3x.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@3x.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@3x.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@3x.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Assets.car
    /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axlithrrzxajtgfxqkefalkhujgj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/asset
    catalog_generated_info.plist

    Non-fat binary /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is not
    armv7. Running lipo -info:
    Non-fat file: /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/x/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is
    architecture: x86_64
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the solution was to move to legacy mode build`from`New Build` and everything worked properly !

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with iOS 13.3.1 signing. It has no solution at this point in time. Current options include:

1. Use simulated device (rather than physical iPhone)
2. Use device with older iOS version
3. Use paid developer account (not personal team)

See this discussion that has up to date info:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504

Answer (score 0):

It has been confirmed that the issue is fixed in iOS 13.4 beta 3 (17E5241d) release.

Comment: any idea on when we are getting access to this ?